# Is the language $L=\{<M>|M \text{ has 24 states}\}$ recursive?

Tags: turing-machines

I know that I cannot use the rice theorem because there are two turing machines that calculate the same function but have different ammount of states. What techniqu can I use to prove that this language is not recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that by $<M>$ you mean "an encoding of the machine $M$ as an integer".

It depends on your encoding of Turing Machines.
We generally suppose that this encoding is at least *computable*, so that we can actually use Universal Turing Machines, and so on. Hence, you should be able to retrieve the number of states of $M$ given its encoding. Therefore, it is clear that the language $L$ is recursive, and you recognize it using the machine that "decodes" its input $<M>$ and checks whether the number of states of $M$ is equal to 24.

Comment: <M> is the encoding ie gödelnumber yes